# Why this onclick alerts only one result from the while loop

Tags: php, mysql

there are currently three posts but when onclick alerts only one post.If I echo the posts insite the  loop,then all three posts are shown,however if I alert them,then onlyone posts is show.plz help or suggest any alternative approach.

```
  $sql=mysqli_query($db3,"SELECT * from user where  id='$id'");
            $num_rows=mysqli_num_rows($sql);

            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

                $posts=$row['posts'];
            }


            ?>
        <span onclick=u(<?php echo $posts; ?>)> <?php echo $num_rows  ?> </span>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function u(posts) {
                alert(posts);
            }
        </script>
        <?php
```

**Update**

Here is second query
 After using the array approach ,If i use fancy box  with $num rows to show all posts in the fancybox .I am again getting the only one result on the fancybox.Plz help

```
            $posts[] = $row['posts'];
```

}
              foreach ($posts as $af){

```
                echo "<div id='#modelbox_id'>$af</div>";}

            ?>


            <a href="#modelbox_id" class="modelbox"><?php   echo $num_rows; ?></a>

            <?php
```

Comment: it is replacing your `$post` variable in each loop and showing you the last result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are assigning a single post row into the `$posts` variable, and then overwriting that variable with a new value on each iteration of the while loop.

Try something like this instead:

```
$posts = array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    $posts[] = $row['posts'];
}
```

Then you will need to print each value of the `$posts` array.

For example, you could implode the array into a string:

```
<span onclick=u(<?php echo implode(', ', $posts); ?>)> ...
```

Comment: ,thank you.It solved the onclick problem. I also  want all posts to be show  on fancybox.but after using  your approach.I am still getting only one post on fancybox.I have ipdated my questionplz help

Comment: @AanaSaeed You shouldn't ask another question in the same thread.  Try to understand how my first answer solved your problem and apply that to your new problem.  If that doesn't work after some experimentation, open a new question about fancy box.

Comment: plz also reciew this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761008/is-this-a-true-long-polling#comment18914635_13761008

Answer (score 0):

Instead try something like this

```
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
            $posts .= $row['posts'].",";
        }
      ?>
    <span onclick="u('<?php echo $posts; ?>')"> <?php echo $num_rows  ?> </span>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function u(posts) {
            alert(posts);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Missed the Qutoes now check